# firebird условия if в запросе

Tags: sql, firebird, if

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с запросом.

```
SELECT * from vzr
LEFT JOIN N_USL_OBST on VZR.OBST = N_USL_OBST.OBST AND
if (N_USL_OBST.OBST = '1') then  vzr.OBST  = '1'
WHERE vzr.D_PST BETWEEN '01.07.2017' AND '31.07.2017'
```

Суть вот в чем:

В таблице vzr есть поле OBST которое содержит либо определенные значения, либо ' ' (пусто)

В таблице N_USL_OBST тоже есть поле OBST, но оно содержит либо определенные значения либо '1'

Нужно взять значения из таблицы vzr.OBST и сравнить ее данные с таблицей N_USL_OBST.OBST и если попадает значения '' нужно заменить его на '1', или наоборот

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Вам нужно выполнить UPDATE или подменять при сравнении?

Comment: Подменить при сравнении

Comment: Простите, а Вам ТОЧНО нужно ЛЕВОЕ связывание?

Comment: не обязательно левое связывание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то OBST в vzr и N_USL_OBST либо равны, либо в первом пусто, а во втором единица. Тогда условие можно записать еще и так, и, ИМХО, это понятнее чем с подменой.

```
SELECT * from vzr
LEFT JOIN N_USL_OBST
  on VZR.OBST = N_USL_OBST.OBST
  or vzr.OBST = '' and N_USL_OBST.OBST = '1'
WHERE vzr.D_PST BETWEEN '01.07.2017' AND '31.07.2017'
```

Comment: `or` может войти в конфликт с `and`, лучше добавить скобки.

Comment: @nick_n_a, если речь про будущие модификации, то я, обычно, пишу подобные условия в одну строку `(VZR.OBST = N_USL_OBST.OBST or vzr.OBST = '' and N_USL_OBST.OBST = '1')`, но приведенный выше пример чуть нагляднее

Answer (score 1):

Решение "влоб":

```
SELECT * 
FROM vzr
LEFT JOIN n_usl_obst 
ON n_usl_obst.OBST = CASE vzr.OBST 
                     WHEN '' THEN '1' 
                             ELSE vzr.OBST 
                     END
WHERE vzr.D_PST BETWEEN '01.07.2017' AND '31.07.2017'
```

Вот только оно  вряд ли будет оптимальным... наверное, если смысл обработать особую ситуацию отдельно и UNION ALL.

Comment: Много значений выдает.... что не так.

Comment: Мало данных для осмысленного ответа. *Много значений выдает* что, есть записи, не соответствующие логике отбора?